# SVG tag mismatch

Tags: xml, svg

I have been trying to write an SVG to draw dig dug (from the Bandai Game of the same name). I have put a lot of effort into mapping all the points onto a polygon but just get the following error.

```
error on line 10 at column 7: Opening and ending tag mismatch: polygon line 0 and svg
```

Here is the code I was using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg height="14" width="14" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" enable-background="new 0 0 386 388" xml:space="preserve">
  <polygon points="4,5 4,6 5,6 5,7 10,7 10,5" style="fill:grey">
  <polygon points="10,7 10,8 11,8 11,10 3,10 3,11 5,11 5,12 7,12 7,14 10,14 10,13 12,13 12,12 13,12 13,11 14,11 14,7" style="fill:grey">
  <polygon points="4,0 4,1 6,1 6,2 5,2 5,3 4,3 4,4 7,4 7,3 10,3 10,4 12,4 12,3 13,3 13,0 9,0 9,1 11,1 11,2 8,2 8,0" style="fill:grey" />
  <polygon points="12,5 12,6 13,6 13,5" style="fill:grey">
  <polygon points="7,3 7,5 10,5 10,7 12,7 12,5 11,5 11,4 10,4 10,3" style="fill:blue">
  <polygon points="4,7 4,8 3,8 3,10 4,10 4,8 5,8 5,10 6,10 6,8 7,8 7,10 11,10 11,8 10,8 10,7" style="fill:blue">
</svg>
```

I have honestly no idea what is wrong with it

I was expecting it to output Dig Dug without his spade but I just get the error above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close all your `polygon` tags:

```
<polygon points="12,5 12,6 13,6 13,5" style="fill:grey"/>
```

Note the slash at the end.

```html
Complete snippet:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg height="14" width="14" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" enable-background="new 0 0 386 388" xml:space="preserve">
  <polygon points="4,5 4,6 5,6 5,7 10,7 10,5" style="fill:grey"/>
  <polygon points="10,7 10,8 11,8 11,10 3,10 3,11 5,11 5,12 7,12 7,14 10,14 10,13 12,13 12,12 13,12 13,11 14,11 14,7" style="fill:grey"/>
  <polygon points="4,0 4,1 6,1 6,2 5,2 5,3 4,3 4,4 7,4 7,3 10,3 10,4 12,4 12,3 13,3 13,0 9,0 9,1 11,1 11,2 8,2 8,0" style="fill:grey" />
  <polygon points="12,5 12,6 13,6 13,5" style="fill:grey"/>
  <polygon points="7,3 7,5 10,5 10,7 12,7 12,5 11,5 11,4 10,4 10,3" style="fill:blue"/>
  <polygon points="4,7 4,8 3,8 3,10 4,10 4,8 5,8 5,10 6,10 6,8 7,8 7,10 11,10 11,8 10,8 10,7" style="fill:blue"/>
</svg>
```